# How to fix "Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored"?

Tags: binance-smart-chain

I made a token for family and friends, mostly to commemorate a loved one, the total coins are their date of birth, nerdy I know, but very me.

The issue I have is I'm only learning to code very recently but wanted to do this so I used a template provided by Binance, so I assumed it would be troubleshooted already.

I also followed a guide on line, howeve AFTER I made the contract and tried to add a image I saw this *error

What does it mean and can I even rectify it now? Any help would be appreciated as it still a few weeks until I plan to give show it.

Thank you :)

Heres the error:

```
Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
   --> myc:352:3:
    |
352 |   constructor () public {
    |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Comment: Can you share your source code? We have no idea of context when the only things have is an error message.

Comment: remove "public"